# USB4 theoretical maximum data bandwidth rate?

Tags: usb, thunderbolt

Thunderbolt 3 used to be limited to 22gbps as per the [technology brief](https://www.thunderbolttechnology.net/sites/default/files/Thunderbolt3_TechBrief_FINAL.pdf):

[image]

and this has been confirmed by many benchmarks over the years. The first [benchmarks](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/zikedrive-usb4-ssd-benchmarked) of native USB4 enclosures  show 29.6Gbps which smells like a PCIe 3.0 x4 limitation to me. It's possible the Intel Core i7-1260P used in the test has a PCIe 3.0 x4 connection somewhere between the CPU and the TB4 controller but that's somewhat unlikely given this block diagram from the [datasheet](https://edc.intel.com/content/www/us/en/design/ipla/software-development-platforms/client/platforms/alder-lake-desktop/12th-generation-intel-core-processors-datasheet-volume-1-of-2/002/on-package-interface-opi/) which shows the TBT4 controller integrated in the CPU which uses PCIe 4.0 to communicate with the outside world so why would it use a slower one inside (this [reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/UsbCHardware/comments/16bqgtg/asm2464pd_usb4_throughput_testing_with_gpu_and/jzgqtxt/) however guesses it might be using the same IP as the [JHL 8540](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/193684/intel-jhl8540-thunderbolt-4-controller.html) and so it might actually be using PCIe 3.0 x4 inside!):

[image]

The SSD is capable of far higher read speeds as well see for example this [benchmark](https://www.servethehome.com/wd-black-sn850x-1tb-pcie-gen4-m-2-nvme-ssd-review/2/). It is of course possible the ASMedia ASM2464PD has a limitation in it somewhere but it's also possible the standard has a limit. So from this test I can't tell what's the USB4 limit: the 40Gbps bus limit or the 31.5Gbps of PCIe 3.0 x4?

Comment: Do you want to know THEORETICAL max speed (as per your title) or real life max speed (as per your details)? That's two different pair if shoes. And then: for what system configuration?

Comment: Theoretical. What's in the standard? It's a tad bit long to read.